# Use widgets with GlobalKeys in navigation

Tags: flutter

My "main" widget has to have the Global key. If I navigate to it with a `pushNamed` or equivalent it generates the exception about duplicate key in the widget tree. I can only `pop` to this widget, but that severely reduces my navigation options and reusability of widgets.

I've included the source of a small repro case, run the app, click `Login` button on the main page, enter 3 chars of login and 3 chars of password and then `Login`.

Any thoughts? Redesigning without the `GlobalKey` is a major undertaking.

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
flutter: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
flutter: The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of
flutter: the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous
flutter: instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
flutter: - [GlobalKey#1c91e navKey]
flutter: This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its
flutter: previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did
flutter: not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still
flutter: thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
flutter: The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to
flutter: GlobalKey reparenting is:
flutter: - Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null,
flutter: hintOverrides: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#147f5 NEEDS-PAINT)
flutter: A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> 
flutter: #1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree 
flutter: #2      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
flutter: #3      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback 
flutter: #4      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback 
flutter: #5      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame 
flutter: #6      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame 
flutter: #10     _invoke  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236:10)
flutter: #11     _drawFrame  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194:3)
flutter: (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyKeys {
  static final GlobalKey navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'navKey');
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => MyHomePage(key: MyKeys.navKey, title: 'Home Page'),
        '/auth': (_) => MyAuth(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Login'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/auth'),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAuthState createState() => _MyAuthState();
}

class _MyAuthState extends State<MyAuth> {
  String login;
  String password;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _doLogin() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if(form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Login')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter login',
                ),
                autocorrect: false,
                autofocus: true,
                validator: (v) => v.trim().length < 3 ? 'Enter more than 3 chars': null,
                onSaved: (v) => login = v.trim(),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter password',
                ),
                obscureText: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                validator: (v) => v.trim().length < 3 ? 'Password should be no less than 3 chars': null,
                onSaved: (v) => password = v.trim(),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Login'),
                onPressed: () => _doLogin(),
              )
            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I also have this problem for some time now and never came up with a solution. Do you think about writing an issue in github? i would vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `pushNamed` new route is added on top of existing one.

Instead of `pushNamed` you can use [`pushReplacementNamed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html), so existing widget will be removed from navigation stack and replaced by new.

Comment: Did you try it? If I modify my sample replacing calls to `pushNamed` with calls to `pushReplacementNamed`  I get exactly the same result.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. I've replaced both calls to `pushNamed` with `pushReplacementNamed`, so navigation stack never holds 2 instances of `MyHomePage`

Comment: I see. First `pushReplacementNamed` essentially takes away the possibility to return "Back" from the next widget. But I guess it's inevitable with the current architecture.

Comment: This definitely doesn't "work perfectly". The pushReplacementNamed method pushes the named route and then disposes the old. You still get the duplicate GlobalKey error.

Comment: pushReplacementNamed worked for me!!